# Dynamically update complex OrderedDict (based on yaml file)

Tags: python, config, ordereddictionary

I'm trying to build a piece of software that will rely on very dynamic configuration (or "ruleset", really). I've tried to capture it in the pseudocode:

```
"""
---
config:
  item1:
    thething: ${stages.current.variables.item1}

stages:
  dev:
    variables:
      item1: stuff
  prod:
    variables:
      item1: stuf2
"""


config_obj = yaml.load(config)
current_stage = 'dev'
#Insert artificial "current stage" to allow var matching
stages['current'] = stages[current_stage]
updated_config_obj = replace_vars(config_obj)
```

The goal is to have the `updated_config_obj` replace all variable-types with the actual value, so for this example it should replace `${stages.current.variables.item1}` with `stuff`. The `current` part is easily solved by copying whatever's the current stage into a `current` item in the same OrderedDict, but I'm still stomped by how to actually perform the replace. The config yaml can be quite large and is totally depended on a plugin system so it *must* be dynamic.

Right now I'm looking at "walking" the entire object, checking for the existence of a `$` on each "leaf" (indicating a variable) and performing a lookup backup to the current object to "resolve" the variable, but somehow that seems overly complex. Another alternative is (I guess) to ue Jinja2-templating on the "config string", with the parsed object as a lookup. Certainly doable but it somehow feels a little dirty.

I have the feeling that there should be a more elegant solution which can be done solely on the parsed object (without interacting with the string), but it escapes me.

Any pointers appreciated!

Comment: FWIW: I think you should be able to capture what's inside of the `${foo}` statements using regular expression groups.

Comment: Thanks! Accessing them isn't a huge problem - my question was rather regarding whether I have to manually "walk" the entire object to replace things or if there's <something> out there that does it for me in one fell swoop.

Comment: weeeeeeelllllll fair question, but `Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam.`

Comment: Noted @alex. I'll rephrase it.

Answer (score 0):

First, my two cents: try to avoid using any form of interpolation in your configuration file. This creates another layer of dependencies - one dependency for your program (the configuration file) and another dependency for your configuration file.

It's a slick solution at the moment, but consider that five years down the road some lowly developer might be staring down `${stages.current.variables.item1}` for a month trying to figure out what this is, not understanding that this implicitly maps onto `stages.dev`. And then worse yet, some other developer comes along, and seeing that the floodgates of interpolation have been opened, they start using `{{stages_dev}}`, to mean that some value should interpolated from the system's environmental variables. And then some other developer starts using their own convention like `{{!stagesdev!}}`, which means that the value uses its own custom runtime interpolation, invoked in some obscure, downstream back-alley.

And then some consultant is hired to reverse-engineer the whole thing and now they are sailing the seas of spaghetti.

If you still want to do this, I'd recommend opening/parsing the configuration file into a dictionary (presumably using `yaml.load()`), then iterating through the whole thing, line-by-line, using regex to find instances of `\$\{(.*)\}`.

For each captured group, create an ordered list like:

```
# ["stages", "current", "variables", item1"]
yaml_references = ".".split("stages.current.variables.item1")
```

Then, you could do something like:

```
yaml_config_dict = "" # the parsed configuration file
interpolated_reference = None

for y in yaml_references:
    interpolated_reference = yaml_config_dict[y]

i = interpolated_reference[0]
```

Now `i` should represent whatever `${stages.current.variables.item1}` was pointing to in the context of the .yaml file and you should be able to do a string replace.

Comment: Thanks for that Alex, and your advice is duly noted. We're already using frameworks that allow interpolation (such as the serverless framework - see https://serverless.com/framework/docs/providers/aws/guide/variables/#variables ) and find that it's working well for us, although as you say there is "thicker" depency on configuration than in non-interpolated configurations. We'll see if we can attack this from another angle. Thank you for your advice and proposed solution.

Comment: @Trondh  No problem!  Hope that helps - and yeah I'm being a little melodramatic; if you're using a managed framework for your configs this is surely better practice than what I was describing.